# page has expired IE 8 while using php codeigniter

Tags: php

I have a login screen once user enters username and password I get a page has expired. It happens only in IE 8 and all other browsers it works fine. I have got some links where they suggest to edit the `session.cache_limiter` to private refer http://shiflett.org/articles/how-to-avoid-page-has-expired-warnings but this also didn't work for me.

Comment: Can you share the exact wording or a screenshot of the error message, please?